# Polkadot-JS wallet staking automation

Tags: polkadot-js, staking, api

We are trying to achieve staking automation to nominationPool.

Is there any solution to get the number of bonded & unbound (unlocked) funds using the Polakdot-JS API?

We would like to fetch the amount(number) of funds in the nomination pool so that we could withdraw them automatically.

Thank you,
The Starfish team

Comment: Just FYI automatic pool compound is on the road-map for Staking.

Answer (score 1):

To get the basic info of the storage of the pool

```
const bondedPools = await api.query.nominationPools.bondedPools(pool_id);
console.log(`----- Storage for bonded pools: ${bondedPools} -----`);
```

And to get the rewards accumulated for the pool (When a members payout is claimed, the balance comes out for here):

```
const rewardPools = await api.query.nominationPools.rewardPools(pool_id);
console.log(`-----  Reward pools: ${rewardPools} -----`);
```

To get the information for a certain pool member (With their Account ID):

```
const poolMemberInfo = await api.query.nominationPools.poolMembers("13KTxXt8FnzoraYSkQNddrmb6sTvEY2VKyg8J9c1jRGPzF5D");
console.log(`-----  Member Info: ${poolMemberInfo} -----`);
```

Then if you want to automate the process to join a pool, nominate, bond tokens.... check the docs about how to call a Extrinsic with PolkadotJS: https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/extrinsics/#nominationpools

Comment: Hi Alex, thank you for your suggestion. Is there a way to get the number of bonded and unbound funds for certain pool member?

Comment: Yes, I have updated the answer